# selected value in carousel

Tags: angular, typescript

i have carousel of years in my project, which selected value i have saved in my localestorage from different page, on my other page on default i want to show value i am getting from localestorage, (by default value is 3), which in this case is 5, how can i achieve that? here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-rkcjdt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) of carousel

**.html**

```
 <carousel #myCarousel height="100%" width="120" cellsToShow="1" [lightDOM]="true" overflowCellsLimit="4">
            <div class="carousel-cell" *ngFor="let year of years">
              {{year.year}}y
            </div>
          </carousel>
```

**.ts**

```
if(getFromLocalStorage('data').hasOwnProperty('period')) {

    }

    console.log(this.data.period); // 5 

      years = [{
        year: 3,
        value: 3,
      },
      {
        year: 4,
        value: 4
      },
      {
        year: 5,
        value: 5
      },
      {
        year: 6,
        value: 6
      },
      {
        year: 7,
        value: 7
      },
      {
        year: 8,
        value: 8
      },
      {
        year: 9,
        value: 9
      },
      {
        year: 10,
        value: 10
      },
    ]

 get data(): any {
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

}

**.service**

```
export function getFromLocalStorage<T>(storageKey: string): T {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a Storage Service, that would get/set/remove/dump/load parameters.
Then assign this Service a constructor in your main ts file use something like this in your ngOnInit method

```
 constructor(private storage: StorageService) {
this.storage.get(AGE_VAL).then((val) => {
    if (val) {
    this.data.Age = val;
  } else {
  // some default value
   this.data.Age = this.defaultValue;
});
```

}

Secondly, in your carusel add an event trigger that would save the chosen value to storage.

```
  public onClickChooseYeats(event) {this.storage.set(AGE_VAL, event) }
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer, i edited my question. i added getfromlocalestorage service and i am checking it with hasownProperty as you see. but how can i check value in my property?

Comment: In ngOnInit  method add the following line:  this.data.Age = this.getFromLocalStorage(your_storage_key). But to save the value in localstorage read the second step described above.

Comment: I am already saving value in my localestorage, i just want carousel default value will be that is saved in localestorage, not 3.

Comment: @feyretamlin you need first check if there is a value of the localStorage parameter for age, and if there is one, you need to assign it to your this.data.Age